# sed replace command working but output is invalid

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, ip

└─$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.7

file "hosts":

```
ip1 == 10.0.0.1
ip2 == 10.0.0.100
```

command executed:

```
sudo -i sed -i 's/10.0.0.1/10.0.0.200/g' hosts
```

Output file :

```
ip1 == 10.0.0.200
ip2 == 10.0.0.20000
```

> The change in ip2 is not expected and an invalid.
> This is just a sample logic need this logic for a Cloud Automation in RPA.
> The Inputs of ip are dynamic vars.

Comment: Use anchor: `sed -i 's/ 10\.0\.0\.1$/ 10.0.0.200/' hosts`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This both helped me resolve it.
i.e.

`$` `sudo -i sed -i 's/10.0.0.1\b/10.0.0.200/g' hosts`

> or

`$` `sudo -i sed -i 's/<\10.0.0.1\>/10.0.0.200/g' hosts`

More Responses are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `.` and add conditions to avoid partial match:

```sh
$ sed 's/== 10\.0\.0\.1$/== 10.0.0.200/' ip.txt
ip1 == 10.0.0.200
ip2 == 10.0.0.100
```

`$` is end of line anchor, if there can be whitespaces at the end of the line, use `\s*$`

Use `==\s*` instead of `==`  if whitespaces after `==` can vary

I'm assuming you can have only one match per line based on given sample, so `g` flag isn't used

---

If `ip1`, `ip2` etc aren't actually part of input, use this:

```sh
$ cat ip.txt 
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.100

$ sed 's/^10\.0\.0\.1$/10.0.0.200/' ip.txt
10.0.0.200
10.0.0.100
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo -i sed -i 's/\b10\.0\.0\.1\b/10.0.0.200/g' hosts
```

1. escape the . ( . -> . ) because  means every character in regex
2. \b to limit the search to this exact sting

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your command as follow:

```sh
sed -i -e 's:10\.0\.0\.1$:10\.0\.0\.200:g' hosts
```

Comment: That'd still match `110.0.0.1`, `210.0.0.1`, etc. Also, `.` isn't special in replacement section and `g` flag isn't needed since `$` can match only once

Comment: Antonio a script that produces the expected output from some small set of sample input is the starting point for identifying a solution, not the end point. [@Sundeep is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68030402/sed-replace-command-working-but-output-is-invalid/68030486#comment120241681_68030486), the script you posted will fail given different input and has other issues.